# Combinations of attributes that can form a key for a relation with functional dependencies?

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I have a homework problem that I am supposed to do. The issue is, any tutorials I've read or watched can't seem to prepare me to solve this problem:

```
Consider the relation R(A,B,C,D,E,F) with FD's:
CDE -> B
ACD -> F
BEF -> C
B   -> D
Which combination of attributes can form a key for R?
```

I don't really know how to even start. From a tutorial, it told me to make a table like this:

```
Left | Middle | Right
----------------------
AE   | BCDF   |
```

Where "Left" refers to only appearing on the left hand side of the dependency, and "middle" refers to appearing on both the left and right hand side.

From there I was supposed to find the closure of `A`, `E`, or `AE` to see which closure would get me to `ABCDEF`. However, I could find no such closure.

Does anyone have any tips to use on this problem, or have any better ideas on how to approach solving it?

Comment: Every textbook on relational databases includes at least one algorithm for determining every candidate key for a relation R. What does your textbook say?

Answer (score 0):

"Left" attributes should be in any key. However, since as you point out the closure of `AE` is `AE` itself, you need to add more attributes to extend `AE`  and make it to a key.

Let us start with adding `B`, i.e., by considering `ABE`. The closure of `ABE` is `ABDE` due to `B -> D`. Since there are still attributes we could not cover (`C` and `F`) we need to continue add more attributes. Let us add `C` and consider `ABCE`. Then, the closure of `ABCE` is `ABCDEF` since `B->D` and `ACD->F`. Hence, `ABCE` is a superkey. Please note that this argument does not mean that `ABCE` is a candidate key (which it happens to be in this case) since it still might contain a redundant attribute.

Moreover, this does not mean that `ABCE` is unique. For instance, instead of adding `C` we could have added `F` and obtained `ABEF` which is also a superkey. Alternatively, instead of adding `B` in the first place we could have chosen a different attribute. Consider the following diagram

```
AE (AE)+ is not equal to (ABCDEF) hence add attributes:
Option 1: Add B. (ABE)+ = (ABDE), not equal to (ABCDEF) hence add attributes:
        Option 1.1 Add C. (ABCE)+ = (ABCDEF), report (ABCE) as a superkey
        Option 1.2 Add F. (ABEF)+ = (ABCDEF), report (ABEF) as a superkey 
Option 2: Add C. (ACE)+ = (ACE), not equal to (ABCDEF) hence add attributes:
        Option 2.1 Add B. This step is not needed since we have already discussed (ABCE) in 1.1
        Option 2.2 Add D. (ACDE)+ = (ABCDEF), report (ACDE) as a superkey 
        Option 2.3 Add F. (ACEF)+ = (ACEF), not equal to (ABCDEF) hence add attributes:
            Option 2.3.1. Add B. (ABCEF) contains (ABCE) already considered in 1.1, hence is a superkey.
            Option 2.3.2. Add D. (ACDEF) contains (ACDE) already considered in 2.2, hence is a superkey.
Option 3. Add D.
       ... 
Option 4. Add F.  
       ...
```